# Object Recognition/Detection?

Tags: java, opencv

Here is my issue, I need to detect a bolt and quarter in an image, I have been searching and found OpenCV but from what I see its not in Java yet. How would you guys go about solving this?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to [use opencv from Java](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/)?

Comment: What do you mean by `OpenCV ....it's [sic] not in Java yet`? OpenCV has Java binding available in its library distribution http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/

Comment: Wow. How did I miss that :S! Sorry! Would you guys use OpenCV to detect the objects mentioned or what would you use?

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a Java interface to OpenCV that you can use. Its open source and hosted on google Code.

[javaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/)

There's also a partial port of opencv to Java. Available [here](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java, I would consider using a fully portable solution, such as [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/).
There are already some object detection toolboxes available ;)

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909020/object-detection-tracking-within-java) SO post for more details.